# Регулярное выражения поиска ФИО для GREP

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Дано: список литературы в журнале следующего вида

1. Фамилия, И. О. Название книги или статьи / Фамилия, И. О., ЕщеОднаФамилия, И. О.// Название другого журнала. -год - № и т.д.
2. Фамилия, И. Название книги или статьи / Фамилия, И. О.//...

Требуется: создать регулярное выражение для выборки ФИО после номера строки и знака табуляции.

Вот, что сделала: `[А-я][а-я]+\,+\s[А-Я]+\.+\s[А-Я]+\.` - выбирает ФИО.

`^[\d.]+\.+\t+[А-я][а-я]+\,+\s[А-Я]+\.+\s[А-Я]+\.` - выбирает ФИО и номер+знак табуляции.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтоб выбирались ТОЛЬКО Фамилия и Инициалы. Заранее всем спасибо

Comment: Так чем не устраивает вариант, который "выбирает ФИО"?

Comment: тем, что "Требуется: создать регулярное выражение для выборки ФИО после номера строки и знака табуляции" и ВСЁ!!!, а то, что я наваяла - выбирает ФИО+номер+табуляцию. А просто под ФИО регулярка не подходит потому, что в строке эти самые ФИО могут повторяться.

Answer (score 0):

Только фамилию и инициалы выбрать без групп захвата (на мой взгляд) не получится, т.к. паттерн встречается не только в начале строки и помимо этого может и не относится к ФИО в принципе.

Если же сделать на ECMAScript, то:

```
^[0-9]+\s+(\S+, *\S\.(?: *\S\.)?)
```

Поиграться онлайн можно [здесь](https://regex101.com/r/YMwPmn/1).